# Scala - Add member variable to class from outside

Tags: scala

Is it possible to add a member variable to a class from outside the class? (Or mimic this behavior?)

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. I already use an implicit conversion to add additional functions to `RDD`, so I added a variable to `ExtendedRDDFunctions`. I'm guessing this doesn't work because the variable is lost after the conversion in a `rdd.setMember(string)` call.

Is there any way to get this kind of functionality? Is this the wrong approach?

```
implicit def toExtendedRDDFunctions(rdd: RDD[Map[String, String]]): ExtendedRDDFunctions = {    
    new ExtendedRDDFunctions(rdd)
}

class ExtendedRDDFunctions(rdd: RDD[Map[String, String]]) extends Logging with Serializable {

  var member: Option[String] = None

  def getMember(): String = {
    if (member.isDefined) {
      return member.get
    } else {
      return ""
    }
  }

  def setMember(field: String): Unit = {
    member = Some(field)
  }

  def queryForResult(query: String): String = {
    // Uses member here
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I am using these functions as follows: I first call `rdd.setMember("state")`, then `rdd.queryForResult(expression)`.

Comment: What you have does't work?

Comment: No, probably because I first call ```rdd.setMember("state")```, then ```rdd.queryForResult(expression)```. I'm guessing that directly after my first call, the member variable is no longer valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the implicit conversion is applied each time you invoke a method defined in `ExtendedRDDFunctions`, there is a new instance of `ExtendedRDDFunctions` created for every call to `setMember` and `queryForResult`. Those instances do not share any member variables.

You have basically two options:

1. Maintain a `Map[RDD, String]` in `ExtendedRDDFunctions`'s companion object which you use to assign the `member` value to an RDD in `setMember`. This is the evil option as you introduce global state and open pitfalls for a whole range of errors.
2. Create a wrapper class that contains your `member` value and is returned by the `setMember` method:

   ```
   case class RDDWithMember(rdd: RDD[Map[String, String]], member: String) extends RDD[Map[String, String]] {
     def queryForResult(query: String): String = {
       // Uses member here
     }

     // methods of the RDD interface, just delegate to rdd
   }

   implicit class ExtendedRDDFunctions(rdd: RDD[Map[String, String]]) {
     def setMember(field: String): RDDWithMember = {
       RDDWithMember(rdd, field)
     }
   }
   ```

   Beside the omitted global state, this approach is also more type safe because you cannot call `queryForResult` on instances that do not have a `member`. The only downsides are that you have to delegate all members of `RDD` and that `queryForResult` is not defined on `RDD` itself.
   The first issue can probably be addressed with some macro magic (search for "delegate" or "proxy" and "macro").
   The later issue can be resolved by defining an additional extension method in `ExtendedRDDFunctions` that checks if the `RDD` is a `RDDWithMember`:

   ```
   implicit class ExtendedRDDFunctions(rdd: RDD[Map[String, String]]) {
     def setMember(field: String): RDDWithMember = // ...

     def queryForResult(query: String): Option[String] = rdd match {
       case wm: RDDWithMember => Some(wm.queryForResult(query))
       case _ => None
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I am getting an error in my class declaration:  
 

```overloaded method constructor RDD with alternatives: (oneParent: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_])(implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Map[String,String]])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Map[String,String]] <and> (_sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext,deps: Seq[org.apache.spark.Dependency[_]])(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Map[String,String]])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Map[String,String]] cannot be applied to ()```

Any idea what this means?

Comment: Did you use a macro to implement the delegation? In this case it is probably a bug (or a missing feature) in the macro implementation.

Comment: I don't think I'm using a macro. All I am trying to do is declare the class RDDWithMember. The error occurs on line: ```case class RDDWithMember(rdd: RDD[Map[String, String]], member: String) extends RDD[Map[String, String]]```.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ExtendedRDDFunctions._
```

will import all attributes and functions from Companion object to be used in the body of your class.

For your usage look for delagate pattern.

Comment: Import in my RDD class? I cannot modify the RDD class code.